# How to properly ask for props on component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component `SinglePost` that is called when another component `Post` is clicked in the main page, and also through path `/post/:id`. The thing is, in `SinglePost`, I call an API through Redux on `componentDidMount`, and then ask for it on `componentWillReceiveProps`. And when you access the component from the URL `/post/:id`, the props throws undefined two times after it loads.

I was following a React/Redux tutorial, to make a CRUD web app with API calls. And, in that project, the props loads fine in both cases (through main page navigation, and from URL). I did exactly the same thing and it doesn't work. Is this a problem, or does it work this way?

This is the `SinglePost` component:

```
   import { connect } from 'react-redux';
   import { mostrarPublicacion } from '../../actions/publicacionesActions';

    state = {
        publicacion: {},
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const {id} = this.props.match.params;
        //this is the action defined on PublicacionesActions
        this.props.mostrarPublicacion(id);

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
        const {publicacion} = nextProps;
        this.setState({
          publicacion
        })

    }

   const mapStateToProps = state => ({
       publicacion: state.publicaciones.publicacion
   })

   export default connect(mapStateToProps, {mostrarPublicacion}) (SinglePost);
```

PublicacionesActions:

```
   export const mostrarPublicacion = (id) => async dispatch => {
     const respuesta = await axios.get(`http://www.someapi.com:8000/api/publicacion/${id}`);
     dispatch({
         type: MOSTRAR_PUBLICACION,
         payload: respuesta.data
     })
}
```

I debugged this and it actually returns the publication. In fact, it renders properly in the SinglePost component. But at first it loads undefined when accessing the component through the url.

RootReducer:

```
   import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
   import publicacionesReducer from './publicacionesReducer';
   import seccionesReducer from './seccionesReducer';

   export default combineReducers({
       publicaciones: publicacionesReducer, 
       secciones: seccionesReducer

   });
```

PublicacionesReducer:

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case MOSTRAR_PUBLICACION:
            return {
                ...state,
                publicacion: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

This is the `Router` component (wrapped into `<Provider store={store}>`):

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path='/post/:id' component={SinglePost} />
</Switch>
```

I actually ask for `(!this.state.publication)` and return null, to render the component. It is working, but it is necesary?

Comment: Firstly, where do you think publicacion will actually come from? Secondly, see https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it comes from an state seted on PublicacionReducer, after calling API on PublicacionAction

Comment: Please give a [mcve], we can't see any of that. Have you done any debugging? Does the request get made? The right value set in the store? The right prop passed?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I eddited. Yes, the request get made. And it works fine. Is just that when loading the page through the '/post/:id' the publication first load undefined. And i have to ask for it on render's method.

Comment: Well why wouldn't it be? You don't *start* the request until the component is mounted. Also you still haven't shown how it's connected.

Comment: @jonrsharpe But, the component mounts at the same time no matter from where you came from. If u click a component that has the SinglePost url, on the main page, SinglePost needs to mount too. Right ? I eddited the SinglePost Component to show the connection.